# Compress large CSV FIle? (500MB)

Tags: compression, zip, 7-zip

I have a CSV-File which is 500MB of size. I am searching for a way to compress is to it smallest possible size. I actually received the file back then in a ZIP-Folder which was only about 50MB of total size, therefore i know it must be possible to compress that file this much. I am using 7-Zip and i tried every possible combination already but i only can compress it by about 20 MB, means from 500MB to 480MB. Do you have any advice on that? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you upgraded to at least 7zip v. 9.38, or even 15.05? Past experience with repetitive XML and CSV files would be to expect about 10:1 compression, as you stated for the source folder. Perhaps there is a memory limitation on the device where you're compressing; try another PC.

Comment: First of all thank you very much. I will try both right now and update this thread. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to "DrMoishe Pippik". He told me that the problem could be a memory limitation of the device i am using to compress the folder. This was exactly the problem. I compressed the file on another device and now it is compressed to 90MB. By the way, i am using the most current 7-Zip Version on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a CSV-File which is 500MB of size. I am searching for a way to compress is to it smallest possible size.

The highest compression can be achieved with lzma2. I suggest using 7 zip on Windows.

- https://www.7-zip.org/